# FriendsOfSymfony / FOSUserBundle another web server port

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am runing Apache on non standard port (22280) on my production server. Application is available on address `myserver:22280/myapplication/`

When I want to log in into my application using FOSUserBundle. I navigate on address `myserver:22280/myapplication/`. The firewall redirects me on the page `myserver/myapplication/login` (without port).

After log out is page navigated on the page myserver/myapplication/ (without port again).

All other links and redirects in the application works fine.

Where is the problem?

```
htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapplication/app.php [QSA,L]


Apache alias:
Alias /myapplication/srv/www/htdocs/myapplication/web
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/myapplication/web">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
  Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Non standard port must be stated in app/config.yml :

```
framework:

   ...

    # router configuration
    router:
        ...
        http_port:            22280
        https_port:           1443

    ...
```

Comment: Maybe there is another problem. When I use myserver:22280/myapplication/app.php it works fine, but when I switch the rewrite engine on the login/logout etc ulrs are returned without port...

Comment: Maybe you should post your .htaccess that defines URL rewriting... Does it rewrite with port in the URL ?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapplication/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>